# Full control permission on Program Files on Windows 7 x64

Tags: windows-7, permissions, user-accounts

How can I set full permission to all folders on my computer?
I have only one account administrator.

Answer (score 2):

You do not want to do this, really.

But in the case you want to loose the security you can on choice:

1. Change permission on C:\ drive property, security tab and ask for recursive.
2. Disable the UAC control as documented [here](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-ZA/windows7/turn-user-account-control-on-or-off)

But I do not advise to do this.

EDIT: edited link for windows 7

Comment: there is UAC control as described in 2. (it's for vista I have windows 7)
I do have "Change User account control settings" with a slider, that i moved to the bottom.

Comment: what should I change exactly in 1?

Comment: I strongly discourage you from changing folder permissions, because this will make it possible for any person, application, virus or mistake to effectively destroy your Windows installation. Similarly, trusted software in the Program Files directory may be altered without notifying you. If you want to perform changes to a directory within Program Files, do so through an application with elevated privileges. (For instance, if you need to edit a text file, run Notepad as administrator.)

Comment: Linked updated. 1. is just if you don't have the permission on the files, but I think it does not disable the UAC, and you will still be prompted for confirmation.

Comment: @Paul Lammertsma, I still want to get full control (like in windows xp).

Comment: Do you lack anything else after deactivating UAC?

Comment: Changing the permissions on the Program Files folder carries other consequences, too. Windows manages data that applications store data in their own directory in such a way that it can be kept separated between different users. Consequently, applications may expect to locate files in the "User\AppData\Roaming" path. By changing the permissions, you will effectively destroy this behavior. Bear in mind that your anti-virus software is also located in Program Files, and by removing the restricitve permission it is more exposed to the effects of malware.

Comment: [Please also see this TechNet discussion.](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/windowscompatibility/thread/8c2eaf70-824e-42e4-83e6-163deceaccfd/) If you understand the ramifications, and **you are sure you want to break your Windows installation**, [see this article](http://www.addictivetips.com/windows-tips/windows-7-access-denied-permission-ownership/). **Again, I urge you *not to do this*.**

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar situation (in my situation I wanted to be able to compare two test virtual machines), and I am describing here the process that worked for me.

We can change permissions recursively on drive c: (as described [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/157461/set-permissions-recursively-on-windows-7)), but one first have to take ownership of all files and folders by using the following command (on a command line "run as an administrator")

```
takeown /f "c:" /r
```

One then have to take explicitly ownership of the system folders such as windows, program files, program files (x86), ProgramData, and any other system file or folder that you want to change the permissions (you can determine which folder you have to take explicitly ownership, by seeing which folder windows denies to change permissions, or by right clicking the folder and trying manually to edit to permissions).

For example to change the ownership for the windows folder execute the following command

```
takeown /f "c:\windows" /r
```

After having correctly the ownership, then changing the permissions recursive will work